# meaning of contour (verb)

Tags: definition

In restoration ecology, we see statements like,

> Roads will be re-contoured, ripped, or seeded if there is evidence of
>   excessive erosion.

What is the meaning of *contour* here? I looked up some dictionaries (e,g, [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recontour)), but I still don't understand what it means in the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dictionary in your link:

> verb (used with object)
>
> [...]
>
> 6. to build (a road, railroad track, etc.) in conformity with the contour of the land.

The shape (*ie*. the height and slope) of the roads will be changed to match the adjacent ground.

Comment: Thank you. I also found this figure (https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0006320711002898-gr1.jpg) that may be useful for people who have the same problem.